# How to remove the glint from Debug stick (1.14 Java)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

I've been trying to make a datapack, which involves using the debug stick as a substitute item in crafting. I'm using this item only because its the only unstackable item that isn't obtainable in survival mode (I think).

I'm making a resource pack for this data pack but the only problem is the glint (the enchanted effect) on the item, I don't know how to get rid of it. I thought that using "parent:generated" would remove these effects, but it didn't. I'm guessing there is maybe a file that I can disable the glint effect (only for the debug stick though).

*Also I do not want to use mods thank you.*

**Note:** *I cannot use nbt tags due to the restrictions in making datapacks and yes I just found out that you can use knowledge books however the debug stick also have other useful functionalities and I want to find out if this is possible or not*

Comment: Re bounty text: Which files do you mean? Also, how would a 3rd party website help in any way?

Comment: Why do you put a bounty on a question, but then don't even answer a comment asking for clarification on what you want? You're just wasting 50 points for nothing.

Comment: Also: "I cannot use nbt tags due to the restrictions in making datapacks" What do you mean? Datapacks put absolutely no restrictions on NBT. And what do you mean with knowledge books? They have nothing to do with debug sticks, other that both are not in the Creative inventory.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear, I got my facts mixed up Fabian, I meant nbt restrictions when it came to crafting (since you can't craft items with nbt tags currently). It was one of the few unstackable items I found that isn't obtainable in survival mc (I found something else tho). There was also the possibility of using the debug stick as a replacement for the carrot on the stick (which had the tendency to attract pigs as I stated in a comment below) so I was curious. I don't regret using my points btw I just wanted to find an answer.

Comment: The knowledge book is not stackable, as well as the regular, throwable and lingering potions of luck and "uncraftable potion". And you can just use any arbitrary non-stackable item and give it a custom NBT tag inside its `tag` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't remove the enchantment from the debug stick without removing the enchantment texture from the game (glint.png). The debug stick will always remain enchanted; without mods this won't be something you can change.

Comment: (except by fully re-implementing all features of the debug stick in command blocks, which is a gigantic project)

Comment: Wouldn't that make a stackable item, though? Assuming you used a stick.

Comment: What do you mean? I meant: You can just use any regular unenchanted item, for example an unbreakable carrot on a stick, remodel and retexture that, use left and right click detection to figure out when to activate what, use raytracing and a full list of all block hitboxes to figure out which block the player is looking at and then a complete lookup table of block states,the order they appear in for the debug stick and of block NBT tags that are directly in the root tag, to figure out which block to set with what state and what data to copy over. And maybe block updates need to be considered.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, you can use any tool with some janky attributes like an unbreakable carrot on a stick with 28 damage. This results in an item thats not obtainable in survival and pretty easy to check for, since you can check for an item of the type carrot on a stick with 28 damage and the unbreakable tag.

For creating such tools, you could use a website like [this](https://geenium.github.io/damage-value-generator/)

This also allows you to change the texture of every item you add this way, which is generated by the website as well

EDIT:

I forgot to mention that these tools do not have the glowing echanted effect, since they're unbreakable via the tag and not via an enchantement

Comment: nbt tags do not work in crafting items in datapacks  (I should have specified the requirements more), also carrot on the stick have the tendency to attract pigs.